# Get checkbox value of items within div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list `checkbox's` within a div which is not a form.

```
  <div id="priceTree">
  <div class="prices"><span class="left"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="price_1"> Small </span><span class="right">5.00</span><span class="center">&nbsp;</span></div>
  <div class="prices"><span class="left"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="price_2"> Medium </span><span class="right">10.00</span><span class="center">&nbsp;</span></div>
  <div class="prices"><span class="left"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="price_3"> Large </span><span class="right">15.00</span><span class="center">&nbsp;</span></div>
  </div>
```

This list has injected elements so may not always have 3. How would I go about getting the id for only the checked checkboxs?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a vanilla JavaScript solution:

```
var checkedCbs = document.querySelectorAll('#priceTree input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
var ids = [];
for (var i = 0; i < checkedCbs.length; i++) ids.push(checkedCbs[i].id);
//return ids;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7YbWm/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$("#priceTree input:checked").each(function(){
   console.log(this.id); 
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gjc56/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').attr('id');
```

---

To iterate over all checkboxes use [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
       console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    });
```

Or,

```
$('#priceTree :checked').each(function(){
           console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        });
```

Comment: i think OP is looking for way to get ids of all the checked checkboxes.

Comment: This will set checkboxes to true and then will get id and will get id of first

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array of checked elements' ids, use:

```
var result = $('#priceTree input:checked').map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get();
```

**[THE WORKING DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/Gjc56/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

To get ids of all checkboxes checked within `#priceTree` div:

```
$('#priceTree input:checked').each(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
})
```